# How to post text content in twitter in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter

I used a method from [this URL](http://amanpages.com/wordpress/sample-iphone-example-project/twitteragent-tutorial-tweet-from-iphone-app-in-one-line-code-with-auto-tinyurl/) (it's supposed to let you tweet from your application). The program ran and sent the message "Successfully Run", but when I went to Twitter the tweet had not been posted.

My code:

```
#import "TwitterAgent.h"

-(void)TwiterPress
{
    [[TwitterAgent defaultAgent] twit:@"Test" withLink:@"http://www.touch-code-magazine.com" makeTiny:YES];
}
```

Everything appears to work as the website said, but the tweet doesn't display in Twitter.

I also want to make a button that will direct the user to a login page and another button that will post the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

use [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/)

its become very easy to share text,image or url.

Comment: i use so many method but i get all time this type of Message it tired to implement ....and i get Message like this ... sorry the application you are using is misconfiguration for FaceBook integration.please download the newest version of the application.

Comment: hey @user1479399 i think u r using old version of Sharkit. download latest version 2.0 from here https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit